# CSS prefers-color-scheme works on Firefox but not on Chrome issue

Tags: html, css

My issue is that my prefers-color-scheme styling only works with Firefox and not on Chrome.

Here is a sample of the code. Now I thought this may be an issue to my certain HTML for whatever reason.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I test this in a completely different file and again, it works in Firefox but not Chrome. Does anyone have any reasons why and how I can fix this?

Comment: You can test it at https://codepen.io/kleinfreund/pen/NmpKZM ... currently not working for me on on Chrome or Chromium 80.0.3987.122 on Linux Mint, but Firefox 73.0.1 is working on the same system.

Comment: Leaving the comment here for beginners like me. If nothing works, check your browser's theme to make sure it's set to System Default instead of Dark or Light. My issue was I tried to change my system's theme to light and dark whereas my browser's theme was set to dark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome only offers support for **[`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)** starting with Chrome version 76, which was released July 30th 2019 (5 days ago from the time of this post). Updating your Chrome to the latest version will show your code applying the `prefers-color-scheme` correctly.

You can update Chrome by clicking the three dots in the top-right, then help, then `About Google Chrome`. This will inform you of your current Chrome version, and prompt an automatic update if you do not have the latest version:

[image: Chrome]

You can check the support for `prefers-color-scheme` at **[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=prefers-color-scheme)**, which shows that Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Safari all support `prefers-color-scheme` under the latest respective versions:

[image: Support]

To check whether your browser supports `prefers-color-scheme`, the following snippet will be red under a dark theme, blue under a light theme, and white if your browser does not support `prefers-color-scheme`:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  html {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird, on Chrome I see blue, firefox I see red, Ubuntu 18

Comment: Today 28 march 2021. Windows 7. My Chrome and Firefox is updated. But prefers-color-scheme doesn't work (. It works on Windows 10 only.

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome for Ubuntu.